# Any way to extract the exhaustive vocabulary of the google universal sentence encoder large?

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-hub

I have some sentences for which I am creating an embedding and it works great for similarity searching unless there are some truly unusual words in the sentence.

In that case, the truly unusual words in fact contain the very most similarity information of any words in the sentence BUT all of that information is lost during embedding due to the fact that the word is apparently not in the vocabulary of the model.

I'd like to get a list of all of the words known by the GUSE embedding model so that I can mask those known words out of my sentence, leaving only the "novel" words.

I can then do an exact word search for those novel words in my target corpus and achieve usability for my similar sentence searching.

e.g.  "I love to use Xapian!" gets embedded as "I love to use UNK".

If I just do a keyword search for "Xapian" instead of a semantic similarity search, I'll get much more relevant results than I would using GUSE and vector KNN.

Any ideas on how I can extract the vocabulary known/used by GUSE?

Comment: Can you please clarify what do you mean by GUSE. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I combine the earlier answer from @Roee Shenberg and the solution provided [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/662) to come up with solution, which is applicable for USE v4:

```
import importlib
loader_impl = importlib.import_module('tensorflow.python.saved_model.loader_impl')

saved_model = loader_impl.parse_saved_model("/tmp/tfhub_modules/063d866c06683311b44b4992fd46003be952409c/")
graph = saved_model.meta_graphs[0].graph_def

fns = [f for f in saved_model.meta_graphs[0].graph_def.library.function if "ptb" in str(f).lower()];
print(len(fns)) # should be 1

nodes_with_sp = [n for n in fns[0].node_def if n.name == "Embeddings_words"]
print(len(nodes_with_sp)) # should be 1

words_tensor = nodes_with_sp[0].attr.get("value").tensor

word_list = [i.decode('utf-8') for i in words_tensor.string_val]
print(len(word_list)) # should be 400004
```

If you are just curious about the words I upload them [here.](https://github.com/petrLorenc/petrLorenc.github.io/blob/master/files/use_4_vocaburaly.txt)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you have tensorflow & tensorflow_hub installed, and youhave already downloaded the model.

**IMPORTANT**: I'm assuming you're looking at `https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder/4`! There's no guarantee the object graph looks the same for different versions, it's likely that modifications will be needed.

Find it's location on disk - it's somewhere at `/tmp/tfhub_modules` unless you set the `TFHUB_CACHE_DIR` environment variable (Windows/Mac have different locations). The path should contain a file called `saved_model.pb`, which is the model, serialized using Protocol Buffers.

Unfortunately, the dictionary is serialized inside the model's Protocol Buffers file and not as an external asset, so we'll have to load the model and get the variable from it.

The strategy is to use tensorflow's code to deserialize the file, and then travel down the serialized object tree all the way to the dictionary.

```py
import importlib

MODEL_PATH = 'path/to/model/dir' # e.g. '/tmp/tfhub_modules/063d866c06683311b44b4992fd46003be952409c/'

# Use the tensorflow internal Protobuf loader. A regular import statement will fail.
loader_impl = importlib.import_module('tensorflow.python.saved_model.loader_impl')

saved_model = loader_impl.parse_saved_model(MODEL_PATH)

# reach into the object graph to get the tensor
graph = saved_model.meta_graphs[0].graph_def
function = graph.library.function
node_type, node_value = function[5].node_def
# if you print(node_type) you'll see it's called "text_preprocessor/hash_table"
# as well as get insight into this branch of the object graph we're looking at
words_tensor = node_value.attr.get("value").tensor

word_list = [i.decode('utf-8') for i in words_tensor.string_val]
print(len(word_list)) # -> 400004
```

#### Some resources that helped:

1. A [GitHub issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/hub/issues/355) relating to changing the vocabulary
2. A Tensorflow [Google-group thread](https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/g/hub/c/6ZH6UzKtwgA) linked from the issue

#### Extra Notes

Despite what the GitHub issue may lead you to think, the 400k words here are not the [GloVe](https://nlp.stanford.edu/projects/glove/) 400k vocabulary. You can verify this by downloading the [GloVe 6B embeddings (file link)](http://nlp.stanford.edu/data/glove.6B.zip), extracting `glove.6B.50d.txt`, and then using the following code to compare the two dictionaries:

```py
with open('/path/to/glove.6B.50d.txt') as f:
    glove_vocabulary = set(line.strip().split(maxsplit=1)[0] for line in f)

USE_vocabulary = set(word_list) # from above

print(len(USE_vocabulary - glove_vocabulary)) # -> 281150
```

Inspecting the different vocabularies is interesting in and of itself, e.g. why does GloVe have an entry for '287.9'?

Comment: I am trying to run this code but getting error for "node_type, node_value = function[5].node_def" . I am using the same version v4. Do you have any updates on how to call it properly?